# How to sum only positive numbers from a few cells (not a range)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I try to sum only positive numbers from a few cells.

How can I do it?

> =SUMIFS(K32,K18,K12, ">0")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF({K32;K18;K12}>0, {K32;K18;K12}, )))
```

or:

```
=SUM(FILTER({K32,K18,K12}, {K32,K18,K12}>0))
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of INDEX?

Comment: @EladBenda Index is shorter solution for ArrayFormula which is needed for calculating over an array of cells - like in your case